# what does "static" mean and the difference of it between different languages(specifically C and Java)

Tags: java, c, memory, static, global-variables

I am currently learning Java and C and get confused with the "static" keyword. In C I mainly use static variables as global variables. In java, I use it for initializing methods eg.
"public static void SomeMethods(){}". also for global variables within classes
eg.

```java
public class ThisClass{
static int var=0;
public static void main(){var++;}
public static void add(){var++}
}
```

what does static mean and whats the difference in java and C?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/ `static` in C.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/ `static` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The static keyword in Java is used for memory management mainly. We can apply static keyword with variables, methods, blocks and nested classes. The static keyword belongs to the class than an instance of the class.

The static can be:

Variable (also known as a class variable)
Method (also known as a class method)
Block
Nested class.

Variable :-The static variable can be used to refer to the common property of all objects (which is not unique for each object), for example, the company name of employees, college name of students, etc.
The static variable gets memory only once in the class area at the time of class loading.

Method :-A static method belongs to the class rather than the object of a class.
A static method can be invoked without the need for creating an instance of a class.
A static method can access static data member and can change the value of it.

Block :-Is used to initialize the static data member.
It is executed before the main method at the time of classloading.

For C : - check this link [https://www.javatpoint.com/static-in-c#:~:text=Static%20is%20a%20keyword%20used,variable%20is%20throughout%20the%20program](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-in-c#:%7E:text=Static%20is%20a%20keyword%20used,variable%20is%20throughout%20the%20program).